# Creating shades between a cluster of line plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I am currently working with a line plot in R that would contain a large number of separate plots (which does make it difficult to read). What I would like to do instead is to somehow create a light-colored shade that captures the range of individual line plots. Would that be possible? This is what I have for my plot:

```
plot(get,Hope2, type="l",col="red", lwd="3", xlab="Cumulative CO2  
emissions (TtC)", ylab="One-day maximum precipitation (mm/day)",  
main="One-day maximum precipitation for South Sudan for CanESM2  
scenarios")
lines(get2.teratons, Hope3, type="l", lwd="3", col="red")
lines(get3.teratons, Hope4, type="l", lwd="3", col="red")
lines(get4.teratons, Hope5, type="l", lwd="3", col="red")
```

So, this gives 4 separate red lines on the same plot (I am likely going to place up to 10 lines, so you can imagine how cluttered that would look without shading them in the background!). Now, let's say that I wanted to create a light red shade that fills from the upper to lower red curves. How should I go about doing that? The idea would be to capture all of the line plots by doing something like this:

http://jvoigts.scripts.mit.edu/blog/assets/plot_shaded_pretty.png

Thanks, and I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Pretty sure this has been answered before. Basic stratey is to create a polugon and fill with the desired color. If you cannot find the answer with a search and want further consideratin then it's still missing a data-object. See [MCVE].

Comment: can you provide reproducible example?

Comment: This can be done in `ggplot` using `geom_ribbon`, FWIW.

Comment: Do you know if this can be done with the base plot command that I am using?